# Multidimensional array calculating

Tags: c++, arrays, string, tchar

I've got an array of arrays of `TCHAR`, where I store file extension.

```
TCHAR *extens[] = { L".*", L".txt", L".bat" };
```

In order to go through it, I'm calculating it's length.

```
int extCount = sizeof(extens) / sizeof(TCHAR);
```

But for some reason the `extCount`'s value is 2. I think the problem is because this is wrong calculation method, but then, how to count the number of elements ("words") in this array correctly?

UPD: I'am passing this array to function:

```
void func(TCHAR *path, TCHAR **names, TCHAR **extensions);
```

When i'am calculating this array lenght outside function it show correct number, but inside it always workis wrong (returns 2 or 1).

UPD2:
I tried to redeclare array like this:

```
TCHAR *extens[] = { L".txt", L".bat", L".txt", NULL };
```

And now inside function i'am doing something like that:

```
TCHAR **p = extensions;
    int extCount = 0;
    while (*p != NULL)
    {
        extCount++;
        *p++;
    }

    extCount = cnt;
    wsprintf(temp, L"%d", cnt);
    MessageBox(NULL, temp, temp, MB_OK);
```

It works, but looks like its not so effective, because of walking two arrays, isn't it?

Comment: You have an array of `TCHAR*`, not `TCHAR`.

Comment: What are you expecting ? You put one string in your array, so the length will be 1.

Comment: @ElderBug, no its always 1, no matter how many elements are there

Comment: @Ivan Petrov `extCount` is 3 for me. Have you re-built the program?

Comment: You should use `sizeof(extens) / sizeof(*extens)`, it's less error prone.

Comment: @ElderBug That will crash on zero-length array.

Comment: @LogicStuff, VS2013 automatically build new application when start debugging.

Comment: @LogicStuff Does it? The operands of sizeof aren't evaluated, right?

Comment: @IvanPetrov `TCHAR**` is not an array, so you can't calculate an array length on it. You have to pass the length with an additional parameter.

Comment: Or preferably you'd have your function templated on array-size and be done with it :-)

Comment: @IvanPetrov I think you'd be better off using `string`s and `vector`s rather than messing around with all those pointers. If you can't use those for whatever reason, and all these arrays are constructed at compile-time, you should make that function a template and let your compiler figure out the sizes.

Comment: @JorenHeit , i need to finish this using in that way. Also maybe i can use pointer and go through array and count number of elements?

Comment: @IvanPetrov See my answer, you can use the templatized version which will deduce N and M as the correct sizes without you having to bother.

Comment: A side note: you are using TCHAR incorrectly. There are two correct ways to use TCHAR: the old, clumsy one is with the _T macro (`_T("x")` not `L"x"`), and the new, preferred one is **never**.

Comment: @n.m. - and what is the newer way?

Comment: Use `char` when you need it and `wchar_t` when you need it. There is zero sense in switching between them at compile time.

Comment: @n.m., okay i'll keep that in mind for future.

Comment: And naturally you don't want to use built-in arrays or pointers either. We have std:string and std::vector.

Answer (score 1):

`TCHAR *extens[]` is an array of pointers of type `TCHAR`. And the size of such an array will be `array_length * sizeof(pointer))`.

Note: `sizeof(pointer)` on a system will be same for all datatypes.

Comment: So i need to get the array length ( to know how many elements are there).

Comment: "sizeof(pointer) on a system will be same for all datatypes". AFAIK this is not guaranteed by the C++ standard. In particular, it is possible that `sizeof(char*)>sizeof(otherdatatype*)` and TCHAR can stand for `char` (if the OP fixes the program to use _T() correctly).

Answer (score 1):

You have an array of `TCHAR*`.

To get the length of the following array:

```
TCHAR *extens[] = { L".*", L".txt", L".bat" };
```

You need to use:

```
sizeof(extens) / sizeof(TCHAR*)
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you have an array of pointers so you need

```
extCount = sizeof(extens) / sizeof(TCHAR*);
```

to calculate its size. However, this assumes that `extens` is still of an array-type. Once you pass it to a function expecting a `TCHAR**`, the array will decay to a pointer and its size information will be lost.

I think your best option would be to rewrite this in terms of `std::string` and `std::vector`. This is C++ so you might as well use its facilities. If this is not possible for any reason, and the arrays are known at compile time, you could templatize the function on array-sizes:

```
template <size_t N, size_t M>  
void func(TCHAR *path, TCHAR *(&names)[N], TCHAR *(&extensions)[M]);
```

The syntax is a bit messy maybe. For example, `TCHAR *(&names)[N]` is read as: "`names` is a reference to an array of `N` pointers to `TCHAR`". Here, the size N is deduced by the compiler as long as you don't let the array decay to a plain pointer.

Comment: The problem is that arrays could be dynamically changed during execution.

Comment: If that is the case, you can't use C style arrays at all like you do in your question. If you need dynamically sized arrays, you definately need `std::vector`.

Comment: @IvanPetrov you are still using static arrays so my answer still holds. The way it is now, your arrays cannot change size.